# Javascript regex for cleaning string value

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to strip invalid characters from a string with js.

My regex currently is as below:

```
var newString = oldString.replace(/([^a-z0-9 ]+)/gi, '');
```

i.e find anything but a-z or 0-9 and spaces independent of casing and replace with nothing - however I also want to allow underscore (`_`), hyphen (`-`) and dot (`.`).

I attempted to update my regex as below but it is not working as expected - after I made the change I found strings with brackets () were not getting those stripped?

```
var newString = oldString.replace(/([^a-z0-9 .-_]+)/gi, '');
```

Am I missing something simple?

Comment: I always use regex 101 to test any assumptions.

See the link below. I've made it multi-line for the sake of the example
https://regex101.com/r/xY1aL3/1

Comment: @benembery - thanks for the link - really useful - never came across it before

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var newString = oldString.replace(/([^a-z0-9 ._-]+)/gi, '');

                                               ^^
```

Keep `-` at the end as it forms a range when placed between `[]`. Now it is forming a range between `.` and `_`. Or you can escape it as well.

```
 var newString = oldString.replace(/([^a-z0-9 ._\-]+)/gi, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape a dot and hyphen:

```
var newString = oldString.replace(/([^a-z0-9 \.\-_]+)/gi, '');
```

Comment: You do not have to escape a dot in character classes.

Comment: Actually dots have no meaning in character ranges. The dash is the culprit.

Comment: within [] you dont need to escape

Answer (score 0):

Put the literal dash last in the character class, or escape it with a backslash. Right now it's allowing an ASCII range of `.` to `_`.

```
var newString = oldString.replace(/[^a-z0-9 ._-]+/gi, '');
```

Side note: you don't need the parenthesis unless you're storing the match for something (and if parenthesis cover the whole match you don't need them then either, because `\0` refers to the entire match).

Answer (score 0):

Use backslash to escape . - _

this should work

```
.replace(/([^a-z0-9 \.\_\-]+)/gi, '');
```

ALSO...
you can also use \w to represent letters numbers and undrescore

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_] == \w
```

Comment: within [] you dont need to escape .-_

Comment: i think maybe you do on . and hyphen

Comment: hmmm a nice point made by vks below! may be using - will use it as range so you might need \ for - but not for .

Comment: i agree with you on that one @Wishy

Comment: Not according to popular opinion or reality even, but ok if you say so...  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_wordchar.asp

Comment: @NotoriousPet0 You're right, I was on my phone and assumed it would act like a lot of other regular expression flavors where `\w` also matches extended ASCII and Unicode characters.